# How to set default values in models? -- in Ruby on Rails 3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In RoR 3.1, "validates" still doesn't have a way of setting default values in the models. Or is there? If not, what's the best way to set default values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One approach would be to set the default in your migration. This will be a property that will get set to your database. You can read more here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html

The other approach is to set a before filter, something like before_save or before_create, and then check if the value on an attribute is nil, you can set it to something.

```
class Abc
   before_save :set_default

   protected

   def set_default
     self.xyz = "default" unless self.xyz
   end
end
```

Comment: Would `unless` be best here or using `presence?` -- I ask since the values could be set as boolean FALSE (which is a valid value).

Comment: or is `self.xyz ||= "default"` best here?

Comment: If you have a boolean than both wouldn't work. That is because false.present? is false. In the second case xyz would be assigned a value even if xyz is set to false. The best option in that case would be to do self.xyz.nil?

Comment: Yes, because self.xyz is false, and this notation will set xyz to default of it is false. Read: http://www.rubyinside.com/what-rubys-double-pipe-or-equals-really-does-5488.html Hope that helps.

Comment: migration are best for setting default value

Comment: You can also experiment with the syntax using rails console and irb.

Comment: migration are best for this cases when the default value is always the same, but when you have cases where the default value is dynamic, like a Time zone for example, the activerecord is your place

Comment: careful - it prevents from the object to be saved. the best approach to it is from the migration

Answer (score 7):

migration are best for setting default value
 write a migration to update column and set default value

```
        self.up do 
           update_column :table_name,:column_name,:default=>your default value
         end
```

Comment: Would love to see a link to a blog post about the reasoning behind this decision. Assuming you only ever create records via your AR models, there's a benefit to have all info about your model (assocations, validations, AND default values) in one place (your model class).

Answer (score 7):

This works well for me

```
class WorkLogEntry < ActiveRecord::Base 

  after_initialize do
    self.work_done_on ||= Time.zone.today
  end

  ...
end
```

Comment: This is a good example, because with Time Zones, it's often not possible to do it through the database and just set a default value for a column. You need to do it at the model level where TimeZones are taken into account. NOTE: I also updated your answer to use the preferred method `Time.zone.today` to fetch today's date, which taken into account the Time Zone.

Answer (score 0):

When a model gets form parameters with empty fileds params of that fields will have nil parameter. So if you initialize same @foo='bar' and user send form with empty params[:foo] then Model.create(params[:model]) will have foo => nil.

1. You can check all paramaters before object will be created
2. You can set default parameters in your database structure through migrations:

   create_table :comments do |t|
     t.text :comment, :default => 'bar'
   end

Comment: That seems quite repetitive if I have a field that is used several places but only set sometimes (and would need the default value at other times). I already have the default value set in the schema but was wondering if rails validations supports it as well in models for added data integrity.