# Titleizing Devise User Name on Sign Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my devise I said that I need additional information from the user when he signs up.
How can I titleize the input of the User when he is signing up?

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :age,
                                                       :country])
  end
end
```

For example, if the user sings up as mark wahlberg, my server should save Mark Wahlberg.

This is my registrations/new.html.erb

```
<div class="form-inputs" id="session-form">
  <%= f.input :first_name, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "First Name", label:false %>
  <%= f.input :last_name, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Last Name", label:false %>
  <%= f.input :email, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "Email", label:false %>
  <%= f.input :age, required: true, autofocus: true, placeholder: "What's your age?", label:false %>
  <%= f.country_select :country, required: false, placeholder: "Where do you live?", label: false %>
  <%= f.input :password, required: true, hint: ("#{@minimum_password_length} characters minimum" if @minimum_password_length), placeholder: "Password", label:false %>
  <%= f.input :password_confirmation, required: true, placeholder: "Confirm Password", label:false %>
</div>
```

I tried looking at the UsersController, but apparently there is no create method in it.

Should I create one or how does devise create the User?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set default values in models? -- in Ruby on Rails 3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950302/how-to-set-default-values-in-models-in-ruby-on-rails-3-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a callback in `User` model:

```
before_save do |user|
  user.first_name = user.first_name.titleize
end
```

Comment: so this should be in the User.rb?

Comment: Exactly, `User.rb`. Remember to restart the server/console after adding these changes. More: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Comment: you can use `before_create` if you only want execute on creation, `before_save` execute in `create` and in `update`

Comment: I've suggested `before_save` because if user is able to edit his name, titleize should be trigerred as well

Comment: yes it works! i added more callbacks and they all work